# Excel Web Part Displays an empty box

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, excel

When adding an excel web part to a SharePoint page, I always get an empty box below any chart or table that I’ve added. I can’t seem to figure out how to remove this empty box. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using modern experience? Which web part are you using & how are you adding chart/table in it?

Answer (score 0):

If it is Modern experience in SharePoint Online, usually delete the web part like this:
[image]
[image]